Yellowfin Delphi API Integration RESTRequest not conneccting
I have a Yellowfin instance which I would like to integrate into a Delphi application. I can use an API provided by Yellowfin for the integration.
When running the API in the Delphi REST Debugger or Postman, it gets a 200 response, then I copy the components (using the option in the Delphi REST Debugger) and paste them on a form. When I right-click on the RESTRequest client and select execute, it returns a 200 response. But, when I try and execute the response in code with RESTRequest1.Execute, I get an error message:

An error occurred: REST Request failed: Error sending data: (12029) A connection with the server could not be established.

What I cannot understand, why would the request return a 200 when I execute by right-clicking on the component, but running it in code gives me the error?

Perhaps your firewall is blocking the app?

@UweRaabe But why would the API return a 200 when I just right click on the RESTRequest component and selecting Execute? How would I know if it is my firewall that is blocking it?

During Design-Time the application is the Delphi IDE, bit when you run the program it is a different application. After all, it is only a guess. Otherwise I would have made it an answer.

@UweRaabe I apprciate the assistance, just wondcering if the issue might not be on the server, as it was working for a minute or 2 now, and again, I'm back to getting the same error, although I can ping the server etc.
